# NativeBase button text gone when parent align is set

Tags: react-native, flexbox, native-base

I have this screen, using NativeBase. It's just a login screen.
It's divided in two parts, first one is with Image logo and signup button, and the second is with login fields.

```
<Container>
  <Content contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 2,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      }}
    >
      <Thumbnail
        large
        source={require("../../../images/logo-splash.png")}
        style={{
          alignSelf: "center",
          marginBottom: 50
        }}
      />
      <Button full transparent>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 12 }}>Doesn't have an account? Sign Up</Text>
      </Button>
    </View>
    <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "flex-end" }}>
      <Form>
        <Item stackedLabel>
          <Label>Email</Label>
          <Input />
        </Item>
        <Item stackedLabel last>
          <Label>Password</Label>
          <Input secureTextEntry />
        </Item>
        <Button full>
          <Text>Sign In</Text>
        </Button>
      </Form>
    </View>
  </Content>
</Container>
```

That just look like this

[image: screen image]

What I don't understand is why the button text is not showing up when styles `flexDirection: "row", alignItems: "flex-end"` are set on the second view?

Here is the same screen without `alignItems`

[image]

[image]

Comment: is this bottom pink block part of your button ??, also could you share the screenshot of the same page while toggle option is on and form view is highlighted, it will be easier to find the issue.

Comment: @warl0ck, That pink block is the button.

Comment: If you make form view to flex direction row, all form elements will try to come in the same row and why would you want input fields in same line ? If you just want the form to be aligned at the bottom of the page remove flex direction and add justifyContent as `flex-end` and just add a paddingBottom of 2 maybe

Comment: Worked like a charm. Make it a answer, so I can accept it. Thanks for the explanation @warl0ck. No need to add paddingBottom

Comment: glad I could be of help, i have posted it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make form view to `flexDirection row`, all form elements will try to come in the same row or line and why would you want input fields in same line ?

If you just want the form to be aligned at the bottom of the page remove flexDirection to be row as by default it is `flexDirection: 'column'` which is what you will need and add justifyContent as flex-end and just add a paddingBottom of 1 or 2 maybe

so your final Style will look like:

`style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'flex-end', paddingBottom: 2 }}`